# Metric TSP with integer edge cost

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, computational-complexity, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms

Given a metric TSP with integer edge cost upper-bounded by a constant $C_{\max}$, can we find an poly-time algorithm solving this TSP instance?

Answer (score 7):

No polynomial-time algorithm exists, unless P=NP.

Indeed, even for TSP instances where all distances are $1$ or $2$ (note that these automatically satisfy the triangle inequality), [Engebretsen and Karpinski](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000005001285) showed that it is NP-hard to approximate TSP within a factor of $\frac{741}{740} - \epsilon$, for any $\epsilon > 0$.